# Fast extraction of coordinates within polygons in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with hundreds millions of point coordinates, and hundreds of polygons.

For each polygon, I want to know which coordinates fall inside.

I am using `sf::st_filter()` for this (see reproducible example below), but, due to the size of my data, this option is still slow.
**Is there a faster solution to do this?**

```
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")

world <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")
germany <- world[122, ]
plot(st_geometry(germany)) # Germany

ex <- data.frame(lon = c(5, 12, 10),
                 lat = c(48, 50, 52))


ex_sf <- st_as_sf(ex, coords = c("lon", "lat"))
st_crs(ex_sf) <- st_crs(germany)

good_points <- st_filter(ex_sf, germany) # here, only 2 coordinates out of 3

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(germany) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = good_points) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it really necessary to use *hundreds millions of point coordinates, and hundreds of polygons*? Sometimes a huge amount of data filtering can be completed in previous instances, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Consider perhaps setting up parallel processing and feeding each instance a subset of the polygons?

Comment: not sure if this would work, but you could define some grid (e.g. 100x100 rectangles) that covers your area of interest.  then for each rectangle record which polygons it intersects with.  your main loop can easily check which rectangle each point is in, if there's only one polygon intersecting with it then you're done, otherwise just check the few which you already know intersect it